# Checking user authentication with ajax request, jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, authentication

I have a nodeJS based server that receives this ajax request

```
    $("#inbox").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "/inbox",
        data: dataString,
        username: 'test',
        password: 'test',
        success: function(data) {
        mails = JSON.parse(data);
        var html = new String();
        for (var i = 0 ; i < mails.length ; i++) {
            html += mails[i].from + ": " + mails[i].subject + "<br>";
        }
        $("#emails").html(data);
            },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#emails").html("bad");
        }
        });
    });
```

How do I get the username and password on the server side? I've checked the request headers, didn't see anything that would help me.

Also: after login, when username and password were validated, I send a response that redirects the user to `/mail?user=username`. How do I safely send the password so that `mail.html` will send it for further requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Express, you'd need to use something like the `basicAuth` middleware first. If you're using that, you can get to `username` using `req.user`. If you want to access the password as well, I think you need to supply your own validation-callback:

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass){
  // validate username/password and return true or false
}));
```

For more information, [look here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#basicAuth).

As for passing the password to `mail.html`: don't. Use sessions instead.